# SQL Error 1054 - Unknown column in where clause - update set where

Tags: mysql

In a unix bash script 'm trying to use the following code.

```
mysql -D${DB_SERVER} -u${DB_USER} -p${DB_PASS} -s -se "\
UPDATE ${DB_VIEW} \
SET wikiid = ${WIKIID} \
WHERE hostname = ${SERVER} "
```

This leads to the following error.

> ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column 'X123456789' in 'where clause'

Any ideas? I'm losing my mind here.

Comment: Please provide your table structure and query with filled variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape the values with single ticks `'`:

```
mysql -D${DB_SERVER} -u${DB_USER} -p${DB_PASS} -s -se "\
  UPDATE ${DB_VIEW} \
  SET wikiid = '${WIKIID}' \
  WHERE hostname = '${SERVER}' "
```

MySQL interprets the value `X123456789` (of `${WIKIID}` or `${SERVER}`) as a column name since it is not escaped as string.

Comment: Holy smokes that's it! Always so simple. Thank you!